# JMeter 3.0 HTTP Put not sending RAW data

Tags: rest, http, jmeter

Recently we moved to JMeter 3.0 and we are receiving the following error, though the same JMX works on previous JMeter 2.13 version

```
PUT Data:
<actual file content not shown here>
```

Implementation used: Default(HTTPClient 4.5.4) and Also tried with HttpClient3.1 and recieved same error.

Any chance to know what could have went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You're not receiving an error , it's a new behaviour.
To allow sending big files along PUT, jmeter has been modified to buffer data and not store it in SampleResult making it possible to sendbig files.

Comment: But this way it is not sending the RAW Data in JSON towards which our REST service testing is failing, the same sampler works perfectly with v2.13

Comment: I suggest you open a thread on jmeter user mailing list witgh more details

Comment: Is it somehow possible to actually see what was sent? I mean the omitted part of `<actual file content, not shown here>`

Comment: You can use nightly build. JMeter 3.1 will be released soon

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue...thought jmeter was doing something wrong since this stuff worked for me in 2.13...hasn't worked since version 3. well..saw a post somewhere that said, using the JAVA implementation of HTTP worked. Guess what? it did work for me too!!! I've been struggling trying to dissect every part of the POST. I was doing it right all along, just needed JAVA implementation of HTTP and voila!

hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.This is the issue with meter 3.0. Downloading the latest version of Jmeter 3.3 solved the problem.